# What's with "Uppercase variable identifiers should not generally be used in patterns..."?

Tags: f#, compiler-warnings

This compiler like:

```
let test Xf Yf = Xf + Yf
```

This compiler no like:

```
let test Xfd Yfd = Xfd + Yfd
```

Warning:
    Uppercase variable identifiers should not generally be used in patterns, and may indicate a misspelt pattern name.

Maybe I'm not googling properly, but I haven't managed to track down anything which explains why this is the case for function parameters...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree that this error message looks a bit mysterious, but there is a good motivation for it. According to the F# naming guidelines, cases of discriminated unions should be named using `PascalCase` and the compiler is trying to make sure that you don't accidentally misspell name of a case in pattern matching.

For example, if you have the following union:

```
type Side = 
  | Left 
  | Right
```

You could write the following function that prints "ok" when the argument is `Left` and "wrong!" otherwise:

```
let foo a = 
  match a with 
  | Lef -> printfn "ok"
  | _ -> printfn "wrong!"
```

There is a typo in the code - I wrote just `Lef` - but the code is still valid, because `Lef` can be interpreted as a new variable and so the matching assigns whatever side to `Lef` and always runs the first case. The warning about uppercase identifiers helps to avoid this.

Comment: Isn't it a bit weird to call me out on function parameters though?

Comment: because pattern matching can be applied to function parameters, i.e. for the sample above: let foo Left = 1.

Answer (score 1):

F# tries to enforce case rules for active patterns - consider what does this code do

```
let f X = 
    match X with
    |X -> 1
    |_ -> 2
```

This is quite confusing.  Also, function parameters are similar to patterns, you can do

```
let f (a,b,_) = a,b
```

for example.  Not quite sure why the third letter triggers the warning though